Streaming fMP4 via ffmpeg using HW h264_vappi encoder
I would like to kindly ask someone who might get to similar issue like me with streaming video with support ffmpeg fragmented mp4 encoding with hardware support h264_vaapi, I will put all possible details I have got so far ....
Pls mind the argument are in array jawa script syntax for spawning arguments
I am using it as I was testing all possibilities I could imagine
Thank you for your time...
Big picture:
I have my project grabing the monitor screen and streming it via NodeJS,
NodeJS spawn external process ffmpeg and taking the fragmented fMP4  and feed HTTPS server.
Doing the lot of Machine learning, picture rec. and such stuff not important for this case
I could run the video in firefox chrome via html5 video embed player perfectly fine.
Working solution Win10
I had one working solution, Win10, nvidia, ffmpeg.
I always saved the first MOOV initial  segment from fMP4 during spawn, and that was feed before the running stream to http client
var args = [ // Argumenty FFMPEG "hardware encoding" do fMP4 {h264} and send to stdout
  '-hide_banner',
  '-y',
  // '-loglevel', '40',
  //'-t', '10',
  '-init_hw_device',
  'd3d11va',
  '-filter_complex',
  'ddagrab=1',
  '-g', '15',
  '-c:v', 'h264_nvenc',
  '-cq:v', '20',
  '-f', 'mp4',
  '-frag_duration', '100',
  '-movflags', '+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof',
  'pipe:1' // Output on stdout
  //`${folderPath1}/output.mp4`
]    

I had to upgrade to AMD graphic card  as ROCm for MLL  like Pytorch is only under linux for now I am migrating the project under linux com-pletely
So I am trying to mimic all the setup but can not get it workign with h264_vaapi under linux.
I have one solution but only with CPU libx264, I am able to extract proper initial MOOV segment and stream video
Working solution linux
linux arg for CPU muxer
var args = [ // Argumenty FFMPEG "CPU encoding" do fMP4 {h264} a poslani na stdout
  '-hide_banner',
  // '-nostats',
  '-y',
  '-video_size', '1920x1080',
  '-f', 'x11grab', '-i', ':0.0+500,80',
  // '-framerate', '25',             // input per-file FPS or when input-undefined
  '-c:v', 'libx264',
  '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',  '-preset', 'slow', '-strict', '-2',
  '-f', 'mp4', 
  // '-r', '25',                         // output fps
  '-g', '15',                         //keyrfame every #of frame
  // '-frag_duration', '100',
  '-movflags', '+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof', 
  '-an',                              // disable audio
  'pipe:1'                            // Output on stdout
  //`./${folderPath1}/output.mp4`
]

This is the part I am trying to get running the hardware acceleration
var args = [ // Argumenty FFMPEG "hardware encoding" do fMP4 {h264} a poslani na stdout
  '-hide_banner',
  // '-nostats',
  '-y',
  '-vaapi_device', '/dev/dri/renderD128',
  '-video_size', '1920x1080',
  '-f', 'x11grab', '-i', ':0.0+500,80',
  '-framerate', '25',             // input per-file FPS or when input-undefined
  '-vf', 'format=nv12,hwupload',
  '-c:v', 'h264_vaapi', 
  '-qp', '18',
  '-f', 'mp4',
  '-r', '25',                     // output fps
  '-g', '15', //keyrfame every #
  // '-frag_duration', '100',
  '-movflags', '+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+empty_moov',
  '-an',                              // disable audio
  'pipe:1' // Output on stdout
  //`./${folderPath1}/output.mp4`

the above solution is not working , I think the issue is +empty_moov together with  h264_vaapi
As i was debuging the initial Segment MOOV and i could not get one working properly
I tested in MP4Extractor.
Even in JS I made a buffer to catch own first 885 bytes of thsi segment i can read  the moov info but looks somethin is missing there.
I can provide more debugs extracted segment.
linux is ubuntu neon kde x11 kernel 6.5.0.45 ,
ffmpeg version tested on distro version 4.4.3, plus another version 7.0.1
and i had to compile mine wiht the vaapi enabled
Compilation info:
  cd ffmpeg-7.0.1 && \
    
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
      --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
      --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
      --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
      --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
      --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
      --ld="g++" \
      --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
      --enable-gpl \
      --enable-gnutls \
      --enable-libaom \
      --enable-libass \
      --enable-libfdk-aac \
      --enable-libfreetype \
      --enable-libmp3lame \
      --enable-libopus \
      --enable-libsvtav1 \
      --enable-libdav1d \
      --enable-libvorbis \
      --enable-libvpx \
      --enable-libx264 \
      --enable-libx265 \
      --enable-vaapi \
      --enable-nonfree && \
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make -j 10 && \
    make install && \
    hash -r 

FYI:
I tried multiple options add some arguments    '-strict', '-2', '-brand', 'iso5', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',  '-preset', 'slow',
My debug
If I will not used +empty_moov flag , and use manualy strip initial MOOV segment from buffer cca 885 bytes end with encoder name i can get workign the stream in VLC player not in html5
Thank you for your time
Update>>>
I will ask directly to ffmpeg guys if they can check and confirm it is really bug
when flag "+empty_moov" is used the MOOV files is smaller around 717Bytes and something missing
I guess it is not passing format and pix even i specified

I did probe and differences are below tested on vers 4.4.4 and 7.0.1
working mp4MOOV:
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 3038 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
not working mp4MOOV
ffprobe -show_format ../init_test_01.mp4
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 2667 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
ffprobe 07-31-2024_test_01.mp4
[extract_extradata @ 0x559a7985cd40] No start code is found.
07-31-2024_test_01.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
var args = [ // Argumenty FFMPEG "hardware encoding" do fMP4 {h264} a poslani na stdout
  '-hide_banner',
  // '-nostats',
  '-y',
  '-vaapi_device', '/dev/dri/renderD128',
  '-video_size', '1920x1080',
  '-f', 'x11grab', '-i', ':0.0+500,80',
  '-framerate', '25',             // input per-file FPS or when input-undefined
  '-vf', 'format=nv12,hwupload',
  '-c:v', 'h264_vaapi',  '-profile', 'high', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
  '-qp', '18',
  '-f', 'mp4',  '-brand', 'iso5',
  '-r', '25',                     // output fps
  '-g', '15', //keyrfame every #
  // '-frag_duration', '100',
  '-movflags', '+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+empty_moov',
  '-an',                              // disable audio
  'pipe:1' // Output on stdout
  //`./${folderPath1}/output.mp4`

]

Try using -f mpegts as the output format. Possibly hevc. On the +empty_moov... You might try +faststart as it moves the moov to the front.

Okay I will test several options with TS I hope i understand correctly just different container, will have to look how the header or what is the part where are stored all info it is similar like mp4 with MOOV.
I believe hevc265 is not suported in html5 emmed video

Yes, just a container switch.  Anytime I've dealt with fragments .ts was always what worked.  The default location in the original MOV spec is at the end of the file.  So faststart is good to do, it willl move the moov to the beginning of the file. Something like ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof+faststart -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts -reset_timestamps 1 -frag_duration 10 output_%d.ts  I don't really know via x11grab.

Okay I will test several options with TS I hope i understand correctly just different container, will have to look how the header or what is the part where are stored all info it is similar like mp4 with MOOV.
I believe hevc265 is not supported in html5 emmbed video  #the -movflags i tried a lot of them even during my debug when i looked directly to moov initial segment  for instance +faststart is nto working, the buffer was same  when fragmentation is enabled it is mentioned in ffmpeg manual on web side# Thank you for comment and your time

I mentioned that in my linux working solution with -c:v libx264 it is working but that is CPU encoding so i guess there migh tbe bug in h264_vaapi

I don't see -init_hw_device vaapi.  That would be good.

hmm  if i understand correctly manual i can use '-vaapi_device', '/dev/dri/renderD128', plus put hwupload in -vf let me read it again , i went over so much stuff a lof off manual working on it like 2 days let me find the example  #here it is there are two ways how to configure vaapi https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI __ and that is workign i cna see in GPU it is encoding in graph

I know that AMD cards use vaapi to hardware decode, where Nvidia cards use -init_hw_device vdpau.  It says here that -c:v h264_vce -init_hw_device vce Is what is used for AMD encoding, and may also require the mesa-vdpau library.  OR hardware encoding with VCN, use the amf device: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_amf -init_hw_device amf output.mp4

One small update I am still curious about mp4 I did few another debugs and that points me there is bug

I would use .mkvafter the pipe, to go to a single file container.  Way better support for lots of things.  Especially timestamps.  I'm a big fan of the matroska container.

I can not use it as I need compatibility format+codec with HTML5 embed video plus also broad support from browsers so firefox and chromium based but thanks for help

No problem.  Have you considered the .m3u8 route?  Unless you are "on the fly" streaming, you can create your segments in advance and use the .m3u8 playlist for the client.  -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts -reset_timestamps 1 -frag_duration 10 output_%d.ts this also generates the playlist.
